# Installing Angular material leads to almost 600 vulnerabilities audit result

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-material

I need the drag and drop capabilities from the `@angular/material` module, but when I install it using angular cli, a bunch of vulnerabilities come out of the audit. The program works, but if I try to run `npm audit fix`, there is an error that the `angular cli compiler module is not found`.

How do I properly fix the vulnerabilities? `npm update` did not work.

Here's the output of `ng --version`:

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.4
Node: 10.16.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.4
@angular/cdk                      8.1.2
@angular/cli                      7.2.4
@angular/material                 8.1.2
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.4
@schematics/angular               7.2.4
@schematics/update                0.12.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.28.4
```

Here's what `npm install` in my project returns, apart from a few not installed peer dependencies:

```
audited 41915 packages in 5.767s
found 596 vulnerabilities (1 low, 2 moderate, 593 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

The audit refers to angular cli, build-angular and so on - so all kinds of different packages.

Comment: You seem to be on an older version of Angular. Update to the latest version of Angular (you may have to update some code, particularly if you use lazily loaded modules), starting with the CLI. You can then use `ng update` followed by the packages you wish to update: https://angular.io/cli/update

Comment: You're right. I solved the issue by downgrading @andulgar/cdk and @angular/material to 7.2.2. if you want, you can post your hint as an answer.

Comment: A lot of them come from an outdated version of lodash before 4.17.12 (a dependency of a lot of other packages) known to cause [prototype polution](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1065). braces, mixin-deep and popper also known for causing such warnings. Run `npm audit` and traverse through each of the vulnerabilities and fix them keeping package & version dependencies in mind. Once you fix the lodash issue a lot of the vulnerabilities will be gone..

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try that. Indeed, lots of vulnerabilities seem to relate to prototype pollution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on an older version of Angular. Update to the latest version of Angular (you may have to update some code, particularly if you use lazily loaded modules), starting with the CLI. You can then use `ng update` followed by the packages you wish to update: http://angular.io/cli/update

Comment: I'd like to add that in this case, I downgraded cdk and material to 7 instead of upgrading Angular. The result is the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `npm install` try `npm install -d` and try `ng update` to update angular version

This will not install npm globally. Then also there will be errors but when you run the project it will be work fine.